# Spring Cloud Consul causes deregistration of ServletContext

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-cloud-consul

Giving in a spring boot application I have a `WebMvc` configuration which extends **WebMvcConfigurationSupport**.

When I add a dependency to:

> org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery:1.2.1.RELEASE

Then I get:

> Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is
>   required to configure default servlet handling

Any hints?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending from **WebMvcConfigurerAdapter** instead, fixed it.